# Android not getting getApplicationContext on service

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, touch-event, ontouch

When i using on touch listener. Inside the touch listener i have called a method. The method parameters want activity and view. When i using `getApplicationContext()` in my service it shows 
`Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.content.Context', required: 'android.app.Activity'`

My code is given below

**MyService.java**

```
chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    private int initialX;
    private int initialY;
    private float initialTouchX;
    private float initialTouchY;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialX = params.x;
                initialY = params.y;
                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                return false;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                float endX = event.getX();
                float endY = event.getY();
                if (isAClick(startX, endX, startY, endY)) {
                    Log.d("LockView", "clicked2");
                    CircularAnim.fullActivity(getApplicationContext(), v)
                            .colorOrImageRes(R.color.color1)
                            .go(new CircularAnim.OnAnimationEndListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd() {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BrowserActivity.class));
                                }
                            });
                }
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                params.x = initialX
                        + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                params.y = initialY
                        + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

private boolean isAClick(float startX, float endX, float startY, float endY) {
    float differenceX = Math.abs(startX - endX);
    float differenceY = Math.abs(startY - endY);
    if (differenceX > CLICK_ACTION_THRESHHOLD/* =5 */ || differenceY > CLICK_ACTION_THRESHHOLD) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**CircularAnim.java**

```
public static FullActivityBuilder fullActivity(Activity activity, View triggerView) {
return new FullActivityBuilder(activity, triggerView);
}
public static void init(long perfectMills, long fullActivityPerfectMills, int colorOrImageRes) {
    sPerfectMills = perfectMills;
    sFullActivityPerfectMills = fullActivityPerfectMills;
    sColorOrImageRes = colorOrImageRes;
}
```

The `getApplicationContext()` is getting in `CircularAnim.fullActivity(MainActivity.this, view)` but it is not in `CircularAnim.fullActivity`

How to solve problem of `getApplicationContext` in `CircularAnim.fullActivity(getApplicationContext(), v)`

Please help me.

Full code of CircularAnim

```
public class CircularAnim {
public static final long PERFECT_MILLS = 618;
public static final int MINI_RADIUS = 0;
private static Long sPerfectMills;
private static Long sFullActivityPerfectMills;
private static Integer sColorOrImageRes;
private static long getPerfectMills() {
    if (sPerfectMills != null)
        return sPerfectMills;
    else
        return PERFECT_MILLS;
}
private static long getFullActivityMills() {
    if (sFullActivityPerfectMills != null)
        return sFullActivityPerfectMills;
    else
        return PERFECT_MILLS;
}
private static int getColorOrImageRes() {
    if (sColorOrImageRes != null)
        return sColorOrImageRes;
    else
        return android.R.color.white;
}
public interface OnAnimationEndListener {
    void onAnimationEnd();
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static class VisibleBuilder {
    private View mAnimView, mTriggerView;
    private Float mStartRadius, mEndRadius;
    private long mDurationMills = getPerfectMills();
    private boolean isShow;
    private OnAnimationEndListener mOnAnimationEndListener;
    public VisibleBuilder(View animView, boolean isShow) {
        mAnimView = animView;
        this.isShow = isShow;
        if (isShow) {
            mStartRadius = MINI_RADIUS + 0F;
        } else {
            mEndRadius = MINI_RADIUS + 0F;
        }
    }
    public VisibleBuilder triggerView(View triggerView) {
        mTriggerView = triggerView;
        return this;
    }
    public VisibleBuilder startRadius(float startRadius) {
        mStartRadius = startRadius;
        return this;
    }
    public VisibleBuilder endRadius(float endRadius) {
        mEndRadius = endRadius;
        return this;
    }
    public VisibleBuilder duration(long durationMills) {
        mDurationMills = durationMills;
        return this;
    }
    @Deprecated //You can use method - go(OnAnimationEndListener onAnimationEndListener).
    public VisibleBuilder onAnimationEndListener(OnAnimationEndListener onAnimationEndListener) {
        mOnAnimationEndListener = onAnimationEndListener;
        return this;
    }
    public void go() {
        go(null);
    }
    public void go(OnAnimationEndListener onAnimationEndListener) {
        mOnAnimationEndListener = onAnimationEndListener;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            doOnEnd();
            return;
        }
        int rippleCX, rippleCY, maxRadius;
        if (mTriggerView != null) {
            int[] tvLocation = new int[2];
            mTriggerView.getLocationInWindow(tvLocation);
            final int tvCX = tvLocation[0] + mTriggerView.getWidth() / 2;
            final int tvCY = tvLocation[1] + mTriggerView.getHeight() / 2;
            int[] avLocation = new int[2];
            mAnimView.getLocationInWindow(avLocation);
            final int avLX = avLocation[0];
            final int avTY = avLocation[1];
            int triggerX = Math.max(avLX, tvCX);
            triggerX = Math.min(triggerX, avLX + mAnimView.getWidth());
            int triggerY = Math.max(avTY, tvCY);
            triggerY = Math.min(triggerY, avTY + mAnimView.getHeight());
            int avW = mAnimView.getWidth();
            int avH = mAnimView.getHeight();
            rippleCX = triggerX - avLX;
            rippleCY = triggerY - avTY;
            int maxW = Math.max(rippleCX, avW - rippleCX);
            int maxH = Math.max(rippleCY, avH - rippleCY);
            maxRadius = (int) Math.sqrt(maxW * maxW + maxH * maxH) + 1;
        } else {
            rippleCX = (mAnimView.getLeft() + mAnimView.getRight()) / 2;
            rippleCY = (mAnimView.getTop() + mAnimView.getBottom()) / 2;
            int w = mAnimView.getWidth();
            int h = mAnimView.getHeight();
            maxRadius = (int) Math.sqrt(w * w + h * h) + 1;
        }
        if (isShow && mEndRadius == null)
            mEndRadius = maxRadius + 0F;
        else if (!isShow && mStartRadius == null)
            mStartRadius = maxRadius + 0F;
        try {
            Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(
                    mAnimView, rippleCX, rippleCY, mStartRadius, mEndRadius);
            mAnimView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            anim.setDuration(mDurationMills);
            anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    doOnEnd();
                }
            });
            anim.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            doOnEnd();
        }
    }
    private void doOnEnd() {
        if (isShow)
            mAnimView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            mAnimView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (mOnAnimationEndListener != null)
            mOnAnimationEndListener.onAnimationEnd();
    }
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static class FullActivityBuilder {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private View mTriggerView;
    private float mStartRadius = MINI_RADIUS;
    private int mColorOrImageRes = getColorOrImageRes();
    private Long mDurationMills;
    private OnAnimationEndListener mOnAnimationEndListener;
    private int mEnterAnim = android.R.anim.fade_in, mExitAnim = android.R.anim.fade_out;
    public FullActivityBuilder(Activity activity, View triggerView) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTriggerView = triggerView;
    }
    public FullActivityBuilder startRadius(float startRadius) {
        mStartRadius = startRadius;
        return this;
    }

    public FullActivityBuilder colorOrImageRes(int colorOrImageRes) {
        mColorOrImageRes = colorOrImageRes;
        return this;
    }
    public FullActivityBuilder duration(long durationMills) {
        mDurationMills = durationMills;
        return this;
    }
    public FullActivityBuilder overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim) {
        mEnterAnim = enterAnim;
        mExitAnim = exitAnim;
        return this;
    }
    public void go(OnAnimationEndListener onAnimationEndListener) {
        mOnAnimationEndListener = onAnimationEndListener;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            doOnEnd();
            return;
        }
        int[] location = new int[2];
        mTriggerView.getLocationInWindow(location);
        final int cx = location[0] + mTriggerView.getWidth() / 2;
        final int cy = location[1] + mTriggerView.getHeight() / 2;
        final ImageView view = new ImageView(mActivity);
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        view.setImageResource(mColorOrImageRes);
        final ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup) mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        int w = decorView.getWidth();
        int h = decorView.getHeight();
        decorView.addView(view, w, h);
        int maxW = Math.max(cx, w - cx);
        int maxH = Math.max(cy, h - cy);
        final int finalRadius = (int) Math.sqrt(maxW * maxW + maxH * maxH) + 1;
        try {
            Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, mStartRadius, finalRadius);
            int maxRadius = (int) Math.sqrt(w * w + h * h) + 1;
            if (mDurationMills == null) {
                double rate = 1d * finalRadius / maxRadius;
                mDurationMills = (long) (getFullActivityMills() * Math.sqrt(rate));
            }
            final long finalDuration = mDurationMills;
            anim.setDuration((long) (finalDuration * 0.9));
            anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    doOnEnd();
                    mActivity.overridePendingTransition(mEnterAnim, mExitAnim);
                    mTriggerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (mActivity.isFinishing()) return;
                            try {
                                Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy,
                                        finalRadius, mStartRadius);
                                anim.setDuration(finalDuration);
                                anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                        try {
                                            decorView.removeView(view);
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                anim.start();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                try {
                                    decorView.removeView(view);
                                } catch (Exception e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
            anim.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            doOnEnd();
        }
    }
    private void doOnEnd() {
        mOnAnimationEndListener.onAnimationEnd();
    }
}
public static VisibleBuilder show(View animView) {
    return new VisibleBuilder(animView, true);
}
public static VisibleBuilder hide(View animView) {
    return new VisibleBuilder(animView, false);
}
public static FullActivityBuilder fullActivity(Activity activity, View triggerView) {
    return new FullActivityBuilder(activity, triggerView);
}
public static void init(long perfectMills, long fullActivityPerfectMills, int colorOrImageRes) {
    sPerfectMills = perfectMills;
    sFullActivityPerfectMills = fullActivityPerfectMills;
    sColorOrImageRes = colorOrImageRes;
}

}
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: please share `FullActivityBuilder` code also

Comment: @Sanjeet I have added full. Please see it.

Comment: `CircularAnim.fullActivity()` requires an `Activity`... obviously it does not work... If you really (**REALLY**!) need to manage views from your service and start animations from it you also must have a reference to the activity on which the animation has to be executed. (the question is very badly placed)

Comment: @Massimo How to excecute the animation.

Comment: You should move your code from MyService to the activity and then call `CircularAnim.fullActivity(YourActivity.this, v)`

Comment: I want to run in service not activity.

Comment: Ok I see where the problem is, for some reason you are trying to pass to FullActivityBuilder fullActivity() a parameter that is an Activity, to inside that function instantiate a FullActivityBuilder. The problem you have got is since you call that method from your service using: CircularAnim.fullActivity(getApplicationContext(), v) you are passing a context and not an activity.

Now I ask you, for what do you need to pass an Activity as a parameter? if you just want to get the context of that Activity at some point, it is better you pass directly the context as I suggested in my Answer below

Comment: I want run an animation on my service. That animation is in CircularAnim.java

Comment: when i pass context it shows the error Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.content.Context', required: 'android.app.Activity'.

Comment: Yes, because you are passing a context as a paramenter in a function that requires an activity. Have you created FullActivityBuilder?

Comment: In my case, I used this.getApplicationContext() and it seems working

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way...

1. public class BaseService extends Service {

   ```
       public Context mContext;

       @Override
       public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           mContext = getApplicationContext();
       } }
   ```

Comment: When i am using this CircularAnim.fullActivity(mContext) it shows same error

Comment: Use Context instead of Activity in CircularAnim.fullActivity constructor

Comment: Then it shows error in final ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup) mActivity.getApplicationContext().getWindow().getDecorView(); line. The error is 'cannot resolve getWindow()'

Comment: I can't see much of your code but you can pass the Context from the Activity and cast that to reference the method.

Comment: ((Activity) getContext()).getWindow()

Comment: Can you elaborate why you reverted my edit? The first line is clearly part of the code and shouldn't be excluded of the codebox.

Answer (score 0):

getApplicationContext() is Related to application and not to activity hence you should use activityname.this or getBaseContext() and you are trying to perform UI Thread operation using Application Context ,Activity UI related operation shold be perform using Activity Context ,not Application Context

Comment: I have used activityname.this or getBaseContext(). But showing as same result. Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to access the Context of your activity from your service, another thing you can try to pass the Activity context in the constructor of the Service. For example:

Activity

```
public class BT_Client extends Activity{

     private BtService mBTService;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        mBtService = new BtService(this, ...);
     }
}
```

Service

```
public class BtService {

    Context myActivityContext;

    public BtService(Context context, ...) {

           myActivityContext = context;

           ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting same error. when i using CircularAnim.fullActivity(myActivityContext);

Comment: @joe as I understand you get the error " Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.content.Context', required: 'android.app.Activity'" when you use getApplicationContext(). This is because you are applying that method over a context, not over an activity. If you already pass the context of the activity you should not call getApplicationContext() again.

Comment: Ok, an extra question: For what do you need the activity in your service? Do you just need to get the context of the activity inside the service or you need it for anything else?

Comment: I have developed an a floating button where running in service. When i click the button then shows the animation and start the activity.